# Bootstrap: Closing others nav menus on collapse via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been new at bootstrap and JS.
Currently, I've two navbar-collapse submenus.
I like to close all others, when another one is opened.

Found this codesnippet:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $('.navbar-collapse').not(this).collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

I placed this in the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` . This event will fired also on the collapse event, but seems to close ALL navbar-collapse elements. So why? And how can archiv my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the demo**

**Method 1**

To collapse all together you can also use something like, you can collapse all the navs which has class "**in**" , because opened collapsible have class "**in**" added. You catch them using like below script close those.

```
 $('#accordion .collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
    });
```

**Method 2**

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading " role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#per" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> <strong>Link 1</strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <!--To make by defualt open a any panel put class "in" (without quotes)-->
        <div id="per" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Link 1    Link 1    Link 1    Link 1    Link 1    Link 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#family" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <strong>Link 2</strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="family" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Link 2  Link 2  Link 2  Link 2  Link 2  Link 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#social" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <strong>Link 3</strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="social" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Link 3  Link 3  Link 3  Link 3 Link 3   Link 3  Link 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm searching for a method which close/hide all other navbar-collapse elements. I don't like to implement this function for each element by using their id.

Comment: This demo is not using ids, the Jquery code is just for toggle plus and minus the icons in it. I have two methods to solve this problem. Use that most appropriate in your context.

Comment: You are using for example #social which reference to a specific element. And "social" is the id.

Comment: @Kinimod without using that part, this section will still work, i will remove the script and you can check that will still work. Edited: I have removed the script, the icon will not toggle now. but collapsible will still work. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but could you please explain why it's work.

Comment: id of the outer div is accordian and in collapsible fiv there is data- parent="accordian" thats why it is working, if that solved your purpose please raise the answer score so that this answer could be marked as accepted and thus could help others aswell. Thanks